# Configuring Postfix, Spamassassin and Procmail to put spam in a dedicated folder

Tags: postfix, spam, spamassassin, procmail

I'm not sure if SF is the good place for that, so sorry if it's not the case.
I'm administrating a Debian server for our company's emails and I'm trying to have the emails flagged as spam by Spamassassin to go in a dedicated folder for each user (like Spam/ or Junk/) but I can't manage to do it. I already have Postfix and SpamAssassin running well (SA flags the spam emails in the subject field properly), but now I must set a Procmail filter to put them where I want.

Here is what I have :
In my /etc/postfix/master.cf, I have a SA rule :

```
spamassassin unix -     n       n       -       -       pipe
    user=spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e
    /usr/sbin/sendmail -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}
```

I tried to add a rule for my spam filtering :

```
spamfilter    unix    -       n       n       -       -      pipe
  flags=Rq user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/procmail -Y -m /etc/postfix/procmail-spamassassin.rc
```

And my /etc/postfix/procmail-spamassassin.rc :

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
LOGFILE=/var/log/procmail.log
VERBOSE=yes
LOGABSTRACT=all

:0
* ^X-Spam-Level: \*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
Junk
```

But it doesn't work and I can't understand why... I have no output in procmail.log so I can't figure how to debug that (my Postfix log doesn't give more). `postfix reload` seems to ignore my changes.
I tried many others configurations, like having a `mailbox_command` in my main.cf to use Procmail, and it isn't better... For information, we use Postfix virtual mailboxes (mailboxes are stored in MySQL, not mapped with Unix accounts).

I know Procmail can run this way cause I have a similar vacation filter in my master.cf and It works :

```
vacation   unix    -       n       n       -       10      pipe
  flags=Rq user=vacation argv=/usr/bin/procmail -Y -m /etc/postfix/procmail-global-repondeur.rc ${sender} ${recipient}
```

Can you see what I did wrong ?

Comment: Wild guess, wrong permissions for the `rc` file?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just have the final mail destination be procmail? There's not need to set up a different transport. Look into the `mailbox_command` value in main.cf.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add "spamfilter" in the "transport" table ?